# JPAQuery to JPASubQuery and vice versa

Tags: querydsl, jpa-criteria, mysema

Is there any way I can get a `JPASubQuery` from a `JPAQuery`and vice versa? I have a `JPAQuery` and I want to reuse it as a subquery but seems like there's not any kind of common interface between the two so that I can perform this transition. The query is quite big and it gets anything but nice rewriting the entire thing as a sub query (actually duplicating the identical `from` part). So I am looking for something like this:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(e).leftJoin(and(or(c1,c2,c3),c4,c5)).where(and(c6,c7,c8));
JPASubQuery sub = query.toSubQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a `JPAQuery` to a `JPASubQuery` like this:

```
new JPASubQuery(query.getMetadata().clone());
```

Solution found [here](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1471#issuecomment-129042759).